# How do I travel to other systems?

Tags: naev

I recently started playing *naev* at the suggestion of some of our users, and so far it seems like a pretty fun game.

One of the problems I seem to be facing, however, is an inability to travel to any systems other than Hakoi and Enegouz. This makes my transport missions quite difficult, and is really keeping me from advancing in the game.

**How can I travel to the other systems, like Apez and Gamma Polaris?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explore around the edge of the sector to find a jump gate.  Just fly around the edges of the sector to look for them.  If you don't want to explore, you can choose to buy a local system map at any planet in the sector with an outfitter (I make it a habit to buy a local star system map for any sector I visit).  Finally, having a jump scanner addon for your ship means you can detect the gates at a much further range, making them easier to find.